# Random position on my dungeon room spawner

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine

Hello i been making dungeon room spawner to my project and the rooms is not spawning on the spawn points like this;

[image]

i tried putting spawnpoint on the center of the rooms but it made it worse.

here is my code;

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RoomSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int openingDirection;
    private RoomTemplates templates;
    private int rand;
    private bool spawned = false;
    void Start()
    {
        templates = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Rooms").GetComponent<RoomTemplates>();

        Invoke("Spawn", 0.1f);
    }

    private void Spawn()
    {
        if (spawned == false)
        {
            if (openingDirection == 1)
            //Need to spawn a room with a BOTTOM door.
            {
                int rand = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, templates.bottomRooms.Length);
                this.rand = rand;
                Instantiate(templates.bottomRooms[rand], transform.position, templates.bottomRooms[rand].transform.rotation);
            }
            else
            {
                if (openingDirection == 2)
                //Need to spawn a room with a TOP door.
                {
                    int rand = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, templates.topRooms.Length);
                    this.rand = rand;
                    Instantiate(templates.topRooms[rand], transform.position, templates.topRooms[rand].transform.rotation);
                }
                else if (openingDirection == 3)
                //Need to spawn a room with a LEFT door.
                {
                    int rand = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, templates.leftRooms.Length);
                    this.rand = rand;
                    Instantiate(templates.leftRooms[rand], transform.position, templates.leftRooms[rand].transform.rotation);
                }
                else if (openingDirection == 4)
                //Need to spawn a room with a RIGHT door.
                {
                    int rand = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, templates.rightRooms.Length);
                    this.rand = rand;
                    Instantiate(templates.rightRooms[this.rand], transform.position, templates.rightRooms[this.rand].transform.rotation);
                }
            }
         spawned = true;
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("SpawnPoint") && other.GetComponent<RoomSpawner>().spawned == true)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

please help i cant make my game like 5 days or something.
and how can i put limit on this spawning rooms?
thank you.

Comment: Where is the pivot of the room?  Click on your room prefab, change the `Tool Handle Position` to `Pivot`, and check where the pivot is located.  You can also check by parenting the room prefab to the spawn point and zero out the position in inspector.  It looks like the pivot is not in the center.

Comment: theres no import setting and that one prefabs pivot is so long but its not spawning on that pivot but ill try finding out it.

Comment: and everytime they spawn they are be on a another spot (i have bad english sorry)

Comment: Ah, the cursed BTP tutorial. Most likely you've positioned your walls slightly offset from the parent empty. To fix this you need to go into your prefabs and move the walls so that they are around the center of the objects origin point. You can make this a bit easier by giving the parent empty a diamond symbol, just like the spawn points.

Comment: I suggest you check where the origin point of each model is, try aligning your model in blender or another 3d modelling program